# Snap Proxy doesn´t work

Tags: proxy, sudo, ubuntu-18.04

I try to install **Conjure-Up** on my Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine with

```
$sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
```

But it always says:

> error: cannot install "conjure-up": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: proxyconnect
>              tcp: EOF

I have successfully set up my *http* and *https proxy* in `/etc/environments`

need help.

Answer (score 28):

It will help.

Example

```
sudo snap set system proxy.http=http://127.0.0.1:3128
sudo snap set system proxy.https=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Comment: A gotcha that affected me: make sure your URL for the `proxy.https` variable starts with `http:` rather than `https:`. Otherwise this won't work.

Comment: I used `sudo snap set system proxy.http(s)=socks5://127.0.0.1:1081` and it works perfectly. But, what shall I do to unset the proxy?

Comment: Is this solution permanent solution? or do we need to execute these commands on every system reboot?

Comment: This did not work for me in Debian 9:
`sudo snap set system proxy.http=http://<hostname>:<port>` which returned
`error: cannot find "system" snap`

Answer (score 8):

Looks like snapd doesn't apply the /etc/environment proxy settings as of 18.04. You can apply an override to snapd service to get around this though.

```
sudo systemctl edit snapd.service
```

Add in the following:

```
[Service]
Environment=http_proxy=http://proxy:port
Environment=https_proxy=http://proxy:port
```

Save then reload:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart snapd.service
```

Snap installs should now go through specified proxy.

Comment: The method you posted here also doesn't work with authentication. Snap should just use the normal $http_proxy and $https_proxy env vars like everyone else. [Here is the ubuntu bug tracker link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1579652) for this problem.

Comment: "A gotcha that affected me: make sure your URL for the proxy.https variable starts with http: rather than https:. Otherwise this won't work." - comment to other post by user @snark
Made it work for me.

Comment: nah, this doesnt help me, otherwise @sn41's answer works well

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
sudo snap set system proxy.http=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080

sudo snap set system proxy.https=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

then you see the download speed is much faster:
           47% 2.19MB/s 7.37s

Comment: Thanks, this worked with SSH dynamic port forwarding